# how to read column of instance-id then print ip address in adjacent column

Tags: python, csv

I have a script which prints out the EBS volumes and their properties in a CSV file as below.
cat vol_orig.csv

```
Attached To,Volume ID,Classification,FQDN,Created On,Volume Type,Size (GiB)
i-c28a836f,vol-21eff464,Service,serv.company.com,2014-09-30T12:57:24.850Z,General Purpose SSD,50
i-8ba09c2b,vol-a2b2d351,Engine,eng.company.com,2015-09-16T05:39:47.521Z,General Purpose SSD,150
N/A,vol-888a63ce,Data,da4.company.com,2015-06-02T05:18:25.390Z,General Purpose SSD,200
```

The N/A in the last line is because the volume has been detached from the instance.

What I would like to have is add one more column adjacent to the instnace-id with the IP address of the attached instance. Not being a programmer, I copy paste and try different scripts and change it a litte to suit my needs. Using this technique I have readied a script which reads the instance-id and returns its IP address. For example, when I do `

> python **getattrib.py** get i-c28a836f | cut -d"'" -f2

` then I get 10.0.134.78 in return.

I am using a shell script to call the volume script which saves output file as **vol_orig.csv**.

> python vol-report.py --access_key key --secret_key key --file
>   vol_orig.csv

How would I utilze the **getattrib.py** script so that the IP address of each instance is printed along side it separated by a comma. 
Also if there is N/A instead of instance-id then without running **getattrib.py** it must print out one more N/A in adjacent column.

I am thinking of having final output as below:

```
Attached To,IP Address,Volume ID,Classification,FQDN,Created On,Volume Type,Size (GiB)
i-c28a836f,10.0.134.78,vol-21eff464,Service,serv.company.com,2014-09-30T12:57:24.850Z,General Purpose SSD,50
i-8ba09c2b,10.0.135.78,vol-a2b2d351,Engine,eng.company.com,2015-09-16T05:39:47.521Z,General Purpose SSD,150
N/A,N/A,vol-888a63ce,Data,da4.company.com,2015-06-02T05:18:25.390Z,General Purpose SSD,200
```

TIA
sbasnet

Answer (score 0):

Use `csv` module Luke. Edit `getattrib` function by yourself.

```
import csv

dct = {
    "i-c28a836f": "10.0.134.78",
    "i-8ba09c2b": "10.0.135.78",
}
def getattrib(att):
    if att == "N/A":
        return "N/A"

    return dct[att]

with open("ebs.csv", 'r') as r:
    header = r.readline()
    reader = csv.reader(r)

    with open("new.csv", 'w') as w:
        writer = csv.writer(w)
        for att, volid, cls, fqdn, cr, voltype, size in reader:
            writer.writerow([att, getattrib(att), volid, cls, fqdn, cr, voltype, size])
```

Comment: Thank you pacholik for your answer. Just to be clear, the code you have suggested is to be added to the script which prints out the EBS volumes , correct??/

Comment: Wherever you want to be executed.